# How to enable "Text Selection" at startup in Okular?

Tags: kde, okular

In KDE's PDF reader "Okular", at startup, text selection is set to "Draw a rectangle around the text/graphics to copy". I'd like to have it set as "Text Selection" by default.

How to do this?

Answer (score 16):

This I read from the official documentation Okular, I hope it's the answer to your question

> Tools !
>   **Text Selection Tool (Ctrl+4)** The mouse will work as a text selection tool. In that mode clicking left mouse button and dragging
>   will give the option of selecting the text of the document. Then, just
>   click with the right mouse button to copy to the clipboard or speak
>   the current selection.

[The Okular Handbook](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdegraphics/okular/okular.pdf). Albert Astals Cid, Pino Toscano

Answer (score 1):

KDE/Plasma specific applications allow the user to edit the options available on the toolbar:

Right-click the toolbar or Settings: Configure toolbars - change under Toolbar: *Main Toolbar < okular_part >*, then filter available actions by searching "Text", and add it to the current actions to the right.

[image]

(Avoid having "Selection tools" in the list of current actions, as it can be a bit confusing: that button only ***shows what selection tool is selected*** , therefore it is useful when no specific selection tools' buttons are on the toolbar; but if the button of a selection tool is in the toolbar, you will see its name appearing there twice - once on its button, once on the "Selection tools" button.)